# Shipping pre-compiled Excel VBA with XMLHTTP

Tags: vba, excel, xmlhttprequest

I have an excel Macro that uses a webservice to authenticate if the user of the Excel is a valid user or not.

I declare my required objects as follows:

```
Dim ObjHTTP As New XMLHTTP
Dim xml As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
```

When I send this file to my end users, some of them get an error saying XMLHTTP is undefined. Using XMLHTTP60 and MSXML2.DOMDocument60 works for them

Is there a way to auto detect the correct ones available on the end user machine ?

Thanks

Comment: Google: vba check reference exists

Answer (score 2):

tldr: Use late binding.

---

You are currently using *Early Binding* which means you have the appropriate library loaded in your references. If the other person does not have that library, then the code will fail as you have seen.

*Late Binding* loses all the autocomplete hints you get with the reference loaded, but it means the reference can be loaded dynamically on another machine.

Your code would become:

```
Dim ObjHTTP As Object
Dim xml As Object

Set ObjHTTP = CreateObject("XMLHTTP")
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
```

The rest of the code would remain the same, and the overhead of dynamically loading the library is so small as to be unworthy of optimization

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the `XMLHTTP60`, `DOMDocument60`, etc. ProgIDs unless you have to support Windows XP. MSXML 6.0 is included with .NET 3.0 and later, and Windows 7 includes .NET 3.5, so all semi-recent Windows installations will have MSXML6 installed.

I believe when you use the ProgIDs without specifying a version you get MSXML 3.0, which is pretty old by now (circa 2000).

Edit: according to Wikipedia MSXML 6.0 ships with XP SP3, so there really isn't a good reason to still be using 3.

Comment: MSXML6 is considered part of the operating system (in-band) starting with Windows Vista and was backported to Windows XP SP3 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xmlteam/2010/07/02/updated-07232010-msxml6-is-now-in-band-msi-setup-headaches-should-now-almost-be-gone/). Because it is part of the operating system, it doesn't have anything to do with .NET. Also, you should not assume that Windows automatically has .NET installed (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110404-00/?p=11043/). I get that you are referring to the wikipedia article, but your answer is a bit misleading.